# Reference Cell value assign in particular cell

Tags: r, excel

Is it possible to get this output in R?

```
=INDIRECT((CONCATENATE(V4, AH4)),TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: In principle, yes, but matrices and data frames are not indexed by letters, like in Excel.  You would need to have what is column `V` in your spreadsheet identify either the variable name or the column number.

Comment: You'll need your data in a dataframe and then google for subsets of a dataframe in R